# Conditionally pass value to web components

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm working with Semantic-UI-react, but my question is not limited to this special framework.

I have the following code:

```
export const renderInputField = function({ input, transparent, meta: { touched, error } }) {
  if (transparent) {
    return renderField(<Input transparent { ...input } />, touched, error);
  } else {
    return renderField(<Input { ...input } />, touched, error);
  }
}
```

which is basically returning a component (`<Input>`) in both cases, and the only difference is the value passed to that component: `transparent`

Is it possible to get rid of if-else and do something similar to this:

```
return renderField(<Input {transparent?'transparent':undefined} { ...input } />, touched, error);
```

the previous line of code fails with the following error:

`Unexpected token, expected ...`

I'm looking for something similar, which can be done in one line.

Comment: Does `<Input transparent={transparent} { ...input } />` work?

Comment: Yes, it does! never thought about that! so basically we can say that was short form of what you suggested?